# Refactor method with int and long

Tags: java

How can I make these 2 method as one? `getSomethingInDB` might return a String with long value or Int. And there are variable type that is long or int, and will be calling one of these methods.

```
private int getConfigInt(String configKey, int default) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(getSomethingInDB(configKey));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOG.error("Error encountered.", e);
        return default;
    }
}

private long getConfigLong(String configKey, long default) {
    try {
        return Long.parseLong(getSomethingInDB(configKey));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOG.error("Error encountered.", e);
        return default;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're catching numberformatexception for `parseInt`, that includes errors in parsing strings that contain a number too large for `int`. Is that intentional?

Comment: what is the data range you expect from getSomethingInDB? If it's gonna return values bigger than Java int can hold, why do you have getConfigInt method? You should keep only getConfigLong()

Comment: @ernest_k not really, what is the right way to do?

Comment: Why not just return a long? It can hold either an int or long.

Comment: @matt int var = getConfigLong(..., ...) what if the return is a long that cannot hold by int?

Comment: This sounds like a problem you'll always have with making the numbers the same value. What do you want to happen if the value cannot be contained in an int?

Comment: That code won't compile. Use another identifier instead of `default`, as this is a keyword.

Comment: Regarding your question: I see no problem in dropping the `int` version of your method, and leave only the `long` version there.

Answer (score 0):

```
private <T> T getConfig(String configKey, Function<String, T> parser, T default) {
    try {
        return parser.apply(getSomethingInDB(configKey));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOG.error("Error encountered.", e);
        return default;
    }
}
```

Then invoke from inside your methods:

```
private int getConfigInt(String configKey, int default) {
    return getConfig(configKey, default, Integer::parseInt);
}

private long getConfigLong(String configKey, long default) {
    return getConfig(configKey, default, Long:parseLong);
}
```

Comment: @AlexRudenko left as an exercise for the reader.